# Website is active but domain name not showing on WhoIs lookup from Linux command-line

Tags: command-line, dns, webserver, domain, whois

I am trying to lookup the WhoIs entry for the following domain:

[anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk)

However, while typing the URL directly into the browser displays a web-page, when I type:

```
whois anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
```

into the Linux command-line I get the following error:

```
No such domain anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid WHOIS registrations are for licensed domains only.

However, if you own the primary domain, you could setup your own WHOIS server that could be queried for subdomains that you register under you.

Code:

whois -h whois.yourdomain.com subdomain.yourdomain.com

It is not difficult to setup a whois server if you want to maintain one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is a subdomain.

You have to lookup the root part of the domain name:

```
$ whois warwick.ac.uk
```

Comment: or `$ whois ac.uk`

Comment: ```whois ac.uk``` indeed! Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. Though CSC also maintain a sort of root domain, so I understand from the time when I worked there. It's some kind of system of layers.